# Does a DataCell class exist

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a couple of utility functions that test for "empty cells" (defined as a `NULL` value *or* an empty `String` value). One for a `DataGridViewCell` and one for a `DataTable` cell.  These seem to be working well enough in general, but I currently have to call the method for testing a `DataTable` cell by passing both the row and column ID from the `DataTable` of the specific cell in question, while the method that tests for an empty `DataGridViewCell` just requires the specific object to test.

```
Public Shared Function IsCellEmpty(ByVal Cell As DataGridViewCell) As Boolean
    If Cell.Value Is Nothing OrElse Cell.Value Is DBNull.Value OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(Cell.Value.ToString) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Public Shared Function IsCellEmpty(ByVal Row As DataRow, ByVal ColumnIndex As Integer) As Boolean
    If Row(ColumnIndex) Is DBNull.Value OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row(ColumnIndex).ToString.Trim) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Public Shared Function IsCellEmpty(ByVal Row As DataRow, ByVal ColumnName As String) As Boolean
    If Row(ColumnName) Is DBNull.Value OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row(ColumnName).ToString.Trim) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

' *** USAGE EXAMPLE ***
For Each CurrentRow As DataRow In MyDataTable.Rows
    If Not Utility.IsCellEmpty(CurrentRow, "CellName") Then
        ' Do Something Here...
    End If

    If Not Utility.IsCellEmpty(CurrentRow, 5) Then
        ' Do Something Here...
    End If
Next CurrentRow

' *** WHAT I'D LIKE TO SEE ***
For Each CurrentRow2 As DataRow In MyDataTable.Rows
    If Not Utility.IsCellEmpty(CurrentRow("CellName")) Then
        ' Do Something Here...
    End If

    If Not Utility.IsCellEmpty(CurrentRow(5)) Then
        ' Do Something Here...
    End If

    ' *** OR ***
    For Each CurrentCell As DataCell In CurrentRow.Cells
        If Utility.IsCellEmpty(CurrentCell) Then
            ' Do Something Here...
        End If
    Next CurrentCell
Next CurrentRow2
```

So, to provide a bit more specificity to the question in the title, is there a `DataCell` class as a part of a `DataTable` that can be referenced similarly to the `DataGridViewCell` class?  Obviously, this is more a matter of personal preference than an actual *need*, but I thought I'd ask in case anyone else has the same question.  In the searching I've done I've been unable to find this specific object class, but I'm certain that someone here can at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Don't provide a method which takes a `DataGridViewCell` for the `DBNull` check. Instead provide one that takes an `Object`. then you can use that for the `DataGridViewCell` and also for the `DataRow`-field object.

Comment: You know that there is a [`DataRow.IsNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.isnull?view=netframework-4.7.2) method?

Comment: @Rango - While a method which accepts a generic `Object` parameter is certainly a possibility, AFAIK, getting the `Value` property of a `DataCell` or other generic object in such a method requires late binding, which I generally try to avoid if possible.  As stated above, this method is used to look for more than just `NULL` values, but also empty `String` values

Comment: Looking over your answer, it seems you've addressed my concerns about late binding, so I'll take another look at my code.  I may have some modifications to make.  Thanks for the input and feedback.

Comment: Both, a [`DataGridViewCell.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value?view=netframework-4.7.2) and a [`DataRow`-field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataRow_Item_System_Int32_) store the values as `Object` anyway. So there no additional boxing/unboxing and no late binding involved (every Object has a `ToString`).

Comment: Using the `ToString` method is helpful in some respects, but the one thing that cannot be tested for a `DataRow(index)` object without late binding is the `Value` property.  Again, not that it's a big deal or even needed in this case, but it's something I was considering when I was reviewing some of my code.  Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184831/discussion-between-rango-and-g-hosa-phat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such thing like `DataCell`. There's a `DataColumn`, but this just stores the column informations like the name and type, not a value in one of the table's rows.

The `DataRow` stores all fields, so you could pass that, as you already do. Instead of passing winforms types to this method you should provide one that is not dependent on specific frameworks(`DBNull` has nothing to do with winforms). Instead you should provide a method that takes `Object`. Then you can use this for your `DataGridViewCell` and also for the `DataRow`-field.

```
Public Shared Function IsValueNullOrEmpty(ByVal value As Object) As Boolean
    Return value Is DBNull.Value OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(value?.ToString()) 
End Function

Public Shared Function IsCellValueNullOrEmpty(ByVal cell As DataGridViewCell) As Boolean
    Return IsValueNullOrEmpty(cell?.Value?.ToString())
End Function

Public Shared Function IsFieldNullOrEmpty(ByVal row As DataRow, ByVal columnIndex As Integer) As Boolean
    Return IsValueNullOrEmpty(row?(columnIndex))
End Function

Public Shared Function IsFieldNullOrEmpty(ByVal row As DataRow, ByVal columnName As String) As Boolean
    Return IsValueNullOrEmpty(row?(columnName))
End Function
```

Comment: The fact that there is no such object is a bit disappointing, but it answers my question.  Thanks for the suggestions and I'll definitely be taking another look at my code.

Comment: Why is it disappointing, why you miss it? A `DataGridViewCell` has feautures which are related to the DataGridView and which are winforms features. A `DataTable` stores just data and is not related to any UI or framework. A field in a DataRow is just an Object. There is nothing else. The field-infromations which are table-wide are stored in the related `DataColumn`.

Comment: Obviously it isn't a huge deal, I suppose I was just hoping there would be a more specific object I could reference/pass.  I can certainly work with what's provided and it doesn't *really* affect me in any detrimental way.  My question was more "thinking out loud" than any feeling that this `DataCell` class is somehow missing.  It just seemed to me that, since there is a `DataGridViewCell` object, it would be logical to have a `DataCell` object.  Your point is well taken, however, and I truly appreciate your input and suggestions.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat: again, a `DataGridView` is something different than a `DataTable`, it's a frontend control. So a `DataGridViewCell` has [a lot of properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell?view=netframework-4.7.2#properties) which are related to styles and other UI stuff. There is nothing similar for a value in a `DataRow`. Reduce methods to take only what is really necessary. If you want to know if "something" is DBNull.Value you don't need the whole `DataGridViewCell`, you need it's `Value`. Don't create dependencies for no reason.

Comment: I completely understand that.  As I stated, I'm not saying that this object is missing or needed in some way, I was just wondering if it existed so I might be able to test the `Value` property of a specific `DataRow(index)` for `Nothing` in addition to testing for `DBNull.Value` and `String.IsNullOrEmpty` as I do/can with the `DataGridViewCell` object.  Again, it isn't necessary or imperative.  Just a thought I had while reviewing some of my code.  Thank you again.